# backup MSSQL database to a client's local disk over network

Tags: backup, sqlserver

I'm trying to backup a `MSSQL` server from linux.  I'm able to connect to the server using `tsql` (from the freetds project), and I'm even able to backup the database on the server using the backup database command, but I haven't been able to download this backup onto the machine I'm using to connect to the `MSSQL` server.

If this was a `mySQL` server, I could download a backup of the database using `mysqldump`.  Is there something similar I can do for an MSSQL server in linux?

Answer (score 3):

Install the mssql-tools package, which includes the sqlcmd utility, on your Linux machine. You can install it using the package manager for your Linux distribution.

Once mssql-tools is installed, you can use the following command to perform a backup:

```
sqlcmd -S <server_name> -U <username> -P <password> -Q "BACKUP DATABASE <database_name> TO DISK='<backup_file_path>'"
```

Replace <server_name> with the name or IP address of your SQL Server instance,  and  with the appropriate credentials to access the server, <database_name> with the name of the database you want to backup, and <backup_file_path> with the desired location and filename for the backup file.

For example:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P mypassword -Q "BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK='/backup/MyDatabase.bak'"
```

The command will execute and perform the database backup. The resulting backup file will be saved to the specified location.

Please note that you may need to adjust the command based on your specific SQL Server configuration and authentication method. Additionally, ensure that the user running the sqlcmd command has appropriate permissions to perform the backup operation.

Once the backup file is created, you can download it to your local machine using various methods like SCP, SFTP, or any other file transfer protocol, depending on your network setup and preferences.

Answer (score -1):

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql) suggests a possible approach: Dump your data from MSSQL into MySQL.  Then you can use the MySQL tools you're familiar with.

There are several suggested methods for the MSSQL -> MySQL dump, so get to take your pick.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use mysql client to connect to mssql server. MSSQL is a Windows based SQL database service while MySQL is a different protocol altogether and MSSQL is a different protocol altogether. It is the TDS protocol that seperates the both of them. If you want to connect to MSSQL service from a tool on Unix, then there are bunch of them. You can use FreeTDS, PyMSSQL,  ODBC/JDBC approach.

If you are looking for some ready made approach tools then there are few I know:

http://sqldump.sourceforge.net/

http://sqlbackupandftp.com/

Take a look at them.

Flimzy,

mysqldump utility supports database backup files to the local disk location, but mssql or sybase do not seem to offer this flexibility directly. In MSSQL, however one can write the database backup files to UNC paths like network shares, which are otherwise can be called as remote filesystem path mounted locally on the mssql database server. There is a support ftp as well directly from the `BACKUP DATABASE` SQL command itself, so one can upload the database backup files as a stream to the ftp upload location. The bandwidth differences and protocol limitations are to be taken into perspective, though. It would be good to use UNC paths if you can setup a winbind/smb share on your local machine and can make it available across the workgroup/AD domain and then accessible to MSSQL server; provided there are network bandwidth limitations. If it is local, I would go for it making sure all the security elements are covered.

If it is ftp, it would be simple, since ftp administration is completely local and you can restrict the upload path in the ftp filesystem area. You need not worry of samba joining/AD user requirements and all. Just ftp service as pure network location with perhaps, security permissions enforced. BTW, make sure your dumps are secured, if it is production, I would be doubly sure to make them secure :-)